# Patch parameter of environment

Tags: environments

I'm using the `taggedline` environment from the `tagpair` package for source attributions in my examples. By default, these get printed in the document font. For less visual clutter, I had considered printing them at, say, `\footnotesize`. However, I haven't been able to find out how to patch the corresponding line in the environment definition with `etoolbox` or `xpatch` without redefining the whole environment in my document in order to change one line. Is this possible at all?

The `taggedline` environment takes the attribution tag as a parameter which is internally handled as `\savebox{\t@g}{#2}`. Basically, I want to place a formatting option like `\footnotesize` before the `#2` part or do something to that effect, anyway.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tagpair}
\usepackage{gb4e}

% Copied & adjusted from
% /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tagpair/tagpair.sty
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{taggedline}[2][0.75]%
  {\def\linewidthfactor{#1}%
%  \savebox{\t@g}{#2}%
   \savebox{\t@g}{\footnotesize#2}% <- can this be done by etoolbox/xpatch?
   \ignorespaces}%
  {\unskip%
   \hfil\penalty0%
   \hskip1em%
   \hbox{}%
   \nobreak%
   \hfill%
   \begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidthfactor\linewidth}
     \narrowraggedleft\strut\unhbox\t@g
   \end{varwidth}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\ex
\begin{taggedline}{(Example 2021: 123)}
\gll Dies ist ein Beispiel \\
     this is an example \\
\glt `This is an example.'
\end{taggedline}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

[image: Linguistic example with interlinear gloss and attribution tag on the bottom right side]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to patch the macro `\taggedline` which is the internal representation for the begin of the environment with the same name. However, because this environment has an optional argument, patching this macro is a bit tricky using the `\patchcmd` macro of the `etoolbox` package.

But you can use `\xpatchcmd` macro of the `xpatch` package for this. Your code will be much shorter then:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tagpair}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\taggedline}{{#2}}{{\footnotesize#2}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\ex
\begin{taggedline}{(Example 2021: 123)}
\gll Dies ist ein Beispiel \\
     this is an example \\
\glt `This is an example.'
\end{taggedline}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same as the output in your question.